# Insert multiple documents referenced by another Schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following two schemas:

```
var SchemaOne = new mongoose.Schema({
  id_headline: { type: String, required: true },
  tags: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag' }]
});

var tagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } }, // value
  name: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

As you can see, in the first schema there is an array of references to the second schema.

My problem is:

Suppose that, in my backend server, I receive an array of tags (just the id's) and, before creating the SchemaOne document, I need to verify if the received tags already exist in the database and, if not, create them. Only after having all the tags stored in the database, I may assign this received array to the tags array of the to be created SchemaOne document.

I'm not sure on how to implement this? Can you give me a helping hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets assume you have input being sent to your server that essentially resolves to this:

```js
var input = {
    "id_headline": "title",
    "tags": [
        { "name": "one" },
        { "name": "two" }
    ]
};
```

And as you state, you are not sure whether any of the "tags" entries alredy exists, but of course the "name" is also unique for lookup to the associated object.

What you are basically going to have to do here is "lookup" each of the elements within "tags" and return the document with the reference to use to the objects in the "Tag" model. The ideal method here is [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate), with the "upsert" option set to `true`. This will create the document in the collection where it is not found, and at any rate will return the document content with the reference that was created.

Note that natually, you want to ensure you have those array items resolved "first", before preceeding to saving the main "SchemaOne" object. The [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library has some methods that help structure this:

```js
async.waterfall(
    [
        function(callback) {
            async.map(input.tags,function(tag,callback) {
                Tag.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { "name": tag.name },
                    { "$setOnInsert": { "name": tag.name } },
                    { "upsert": true, "new": true },
                    callback
                )
            },callback);
        },
        function(tags,callback) {
            Model.findOneAndUpdate(
                { "id_headline": input.id_headline },
                { "$addToSet": { 
                    "tags": { "$each": tags.map(function(tag) { return tag._id }) }
                }},
                { "upsert": true, "new": true },
                callback
            )
        }
    ],
    function(err,result) {
        // if err then do something to report it, otherwise it's done.
    }
)
```

So the [`async.waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) is a special flow control method that will pass the result returned from each of the functions specified in the array of arguments to the next one, right until the end of execution where you can optionally pass in the result of the final function in the list. It basically "cascades" or "waterfalls" results down to each step. This is wanted to pass in the results of the "tags" creation to the main model creation/modification.

The [`async.map`](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) within the first executed stage looks at each of the elements within the array of the input. So for each item contained in "tags", the `.findOneAndUpdate()` method is called to look for and possibly create if not found, the specified "tag" entry in the collection.

Since the output of `.map()` is going to be an array of those documents, it is simply passed through to the next stage. Therefore each iteration returns a document, when the iteration is complete you have all documents.

The next usage of `.findOneAndUpdate()` with "upsert" is optional, and of course considers that the document with the matching "id_headline" may or may not exist. The same case is true that if it is there then the "update" is processed, if not then it is simply created. You could optionally `.insert()` or `.create()` if the document was known not to be there, but the "update" action gives some interesting options.

Namely here is the usage of [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/), where if the document already existed then the specified items would be "added" to any content that was already there, and of course as a "set", any items already present would not be new additions. Note that only the `_id` fields are required here when adding to the array with an atomic operator, hence the `.map()` function employed.

An alternate case on "updating" could be to simply "replace" the array content using the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) atomic operation if it was the intent to only store those items that were mentioned in the input and no others.

In a similar manner the [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) shown when "creating"/"looking for" items in "Tags" makes sure that there is only actual "modification" when the object is "created/inserted", and that removes some write overhead on the server.

So the basic priciples of using `.findOneAndUpdate()` at least for the "Tags" entries is the most optimal way of handling this. This avoids double handling such as:

- Querying to see if the document exists by name
- if No result is returned, then send an additional statement to create one

That means two operations to the database with communication back and forth, which the actions here using ["upserts"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) simplifies into a single request for each item.

Comment: Thank you so much! Awesome answer with a great explanation :D